# Increase each number value by 15% in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-update

I have a table **Emp** with a **Name** and **Salary** columns respectively. I want to increase each salary by 15% in **MSSQL**.

The query below is just for a single update and I still can't get it done...

```
UPDATE    Emp
SET       Salary = '(@Salary / 100) * 15 + @salary'

WHERE Name='Zangiv'
```

I need a single query statement to update multiple rows at once.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
UPDATE Emp
SET salary = salary * 1.15
WHERE Name = 'Zangiv'
```

Answer (score 3):

Given your stated requirement:

> I want to increase each salary by 15% in MSSQL

The following query will increase **ALL** salaries by 15%.

```
UPDATE    Emp
SET       Salary = Salary * 1.15
```

If you don't actually want to update **ALL** rows in your table, use a `WHERE` clause as appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on whether you meant "multiple rows with the name `Zangiv`" or all rows:

```
UPDATE dbo.Emp
SET Salary = Salary * 1.15
--WHERE Name = 'Zangiv';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE Emp SET Salary = Salary * 1.15;
```

would increase the salary for all employees by 15%;

Answer (score 2):

SQL 2008 onwards

```
UPDATE Emp
SET Salary *= 1.15
```

otherwise

```
UPDATE Emp
SET Salary = Salary * 1.15
```

Answer (score 1):

**Query to update single specific row**

```
UPDATE Emp
SET Salary = Salary*15/100
WHERE Name = 'Zangiv'
```

**Query to update all rows**

```
UPDATE Emp SET Salary = Salary*15/100
```

Answer (score -1):

ive done the same thing instead of increasing ive decreased the value by 20% which goes something like this

> SET Cost = Cost - (cost * 0.20)
>   where SerialNumber = 'mmmmmm'

Comment: OP didn't ask for decrease but if he was asking for it, `Cost = Cost * 0.8` would be more straightforward.